# Translating Interface Builder settings into Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, interface-builder

In order to understand the logic of the Interface Builder, it would be useful to have a tool which takes an xcode project (cocoa/objc) created with the help of the IB and produces an "equivalent" project where all (or some of the) IB settings have been translated into objc code.

Does such a tool exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does such a tool exist?

Not as far as I know.

> it would be useful to have a tool which takes an xcode project
>   (cocoa/objc) created with the help of the IB and produces
>   an "equivalent" project where all (or some of the) IB settings
>   have been translated into objc code.

It probably wouldn't help nearly as much as you might think. You don't really need to understand "the logic" of Interface Builder in great detail, you just need to understand what it does and doesn't do.

The part of Xcode that we still refer to as Interface Builder (even though it hasn't been a separate application for longer than some Xcode users have been alive) essentially just creates objects, configures them, connects them together, and serializes the resulting object graphs to a file. It **doesn't<sup>*</sup> generate any code**, and it doesn't do anything magical. When your app runs, the contents of a storyboard or xib file is read and deserialized to create an object graph matching the one you specified in IB.

If you want to see how the objects that IB creates are configured, you can either look in the xib or storyboard file, or you can inspect the objects in your program. The serialized files mostly just call out objects and relationships between them. Here's a label from a xib file:

```
<label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Apple" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="HDj-93-0Hv">
    <rect key="frame" x="59" y="114" width="45" height="21"/>
    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
    <nil key="textColor"/>
    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
</label>
```

Everything there is to know about the label itself is there, and it doesn't take a lot of figuring to see how to write Objective-C or Swift code that creates a label and configures it the same way. Probably the hardest part is examining relationships with other objects, such as autolayout constraints. For that, look at the `id` field above:

```
id="HDj-93-0Hv"
```

That ID is the link to other objects. Here's a constraint:

```
<constraint firstItem="HDj-93-0Hv" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="vUN-kp-3ea" secondAttribute="top" constant="70" id="rM0-in-vEv"/>
```

This is just another object specification, but since a constraint necessarily references other objects, you see some ID's included. There's the ID of the label specified above, as well as the ID of the enclosing view, and also the ID of the constraint itself.

The other approach is to look at the objects in your app. You can look at the properties of objects in the debugger, see what they're connected to, print out their constraints, etc. Use the view hierarchy tool to get a good look at how your views are arranged.

I'm sure it sounds like picking through XML or using the debugger would get complicated if you have a large storyboard with lots of views and lots of relationships between them, and you're not wrong. But if you had a tool that converted a storyboard into Objective-C or Swift code, the resulting code wouldn't be any less complex.

---

<sup>*</sup>The whole "it doesn't generate code" idea goes out the window with SwiftUI, because when you work in that framework's declarative style Xcode maps the  graphical view layout to your code.

Comment: "It doesn't generate any code" Well, in a way it does. I mean, if you design in IB a UILabel with a certain frame and a certain font, then at runtime, _someone_ needs to create a UILabel and assign it that frame and that font (and put it into the same superview). That's a _kind_ of code generation. In other words, in a very real sense, the nib consists of instructions, and at runtime, those instructions are obeyed. So it isn't entirely unreasonable for the OP to ask for those instructions.

Comment: And really, the OP's idea here is not so different from, say, PaintCode, which lets you do for a drawn image exactly the sort of thing described, namely generate the code instructions that would result in the same image. Similarly, Zeplin lets you design a UILabel label and gives you the code for generating that label.

Comment: @matt You're conflating code and data. Sure, you could call the XML in a storyboard file "code," but the important idea here is that at no point does IB emit any Objective-C or Swift code; the info in the XML file is literally serialized objects. The *reason* that's important is that a lot of other GUI tools do generate source code instead of serialized objects, and people coming from other environments or who just make an assumption about how IB works find it confusing until someone explains it.

Comment: @matt *So it isn't entirely unreasonable for the OP to ask for those instructions.* I agree!  And the OP already has those "instructions", if that's what we're calling the XML. But the OP is asking for those instructions to be translated into the string of Objective-C calls that one would write to generate the equivalent object graph if the XML didn't exist. My answer, in a nutshell, is *I don't think that exists, and I don't think it'd be as useful as you'd think, and here's why...*

Comment: I agree with all you say, but I still think what the OP wants is reasonable to want. Suppose you decide to abandon your app’s use of nibs and do it all in code instead. That’s a big pain, and you’d think it could be automated.

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't reasonable, only that it seems not to exist and that for the OP's purpose of understanding "the logic of the Interface Builder" it's probably wouldn't help more than reading the "instructions"/data in the XML.

Comment: Yes, I think we are in broad agreement. I hope our comments survive, as they form a useful footnote to your answer.

Comment: I'd also agree with you that there are uses for having code instead of canned objects, and that's surely part of the motivation for SwiftUI. Cheers, and thanks for your long history of great answers.

Comment: @Caleb, thanks! That was useful info. As for the usefulness of the "tool", it depends on personal taste and background. For me it's much easier to read (and debug!) objc code rather then a large xml file which (to start with) doesn't fit in my screen. Information is "in plain view" in a code, while in the IB it could be concealed in some graphic detail inside a tab (like the fact that an arrow is dotted instead of solid in the autoresize section of the "size inspector"). Also, viewing this generated code could have didactic value for _learning_ AppKit.